# Which one probability is more likely?

Tags: probability

[image]

- A. The quantity in Column A is greater
- B. The quantity in Column B is greater
- C. The two quantities are equal
- D. The relationship cannot be determined from the information given
  Which will be the answer?

> Because the fair coin is equal probably so I thought Quantity B is greater. But the answer is given $C$.

Comment: Your answer would be right if we toss $6$ times. For more heads than tails and more tails than heads are equally likely. But a tie is also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem is determining the probability that, given two heads and given two tails, that the fifth coin then flipped will land "heads": as we know, that probability is $\frac 12$, so C is indeed the correct answer.

That's also the probability of getting more tails than heads.

Answer (score 1):

If the coin is fair, then the probability of getting heads and tails are the same. This means that in the long run (an infinite number of trials) half of the time there will be more heads and half of the time there will be more tails, so the quantities are equal.

Any *one* set of 5 must have more of one than the other,but in 1000000000000 sets of 5, half will have more heads and half will have more tails, so the answer remains one half.

Answer (score 0):

Another very explicit way to look at this is simply to analyze all the possible sequences of coin flips. There are 32 different sequences of coin flips (two possibilities for each flip, five flips, so `2^5 = 32`), and each sequence has the same probability of appearing (because each flip is independent of the other flips). I'll use a zero for tails and a one for heads, which will make the allusion to binary counting obvious:

```
 Flip1 | Flip2 | Flip3 | Flip4 | Flip5 | Heads |
---------------------------------------+--------
   0       0       0       0       0   |   0
   0       0       0       0       1   |   1
   0       0       0       1       0   |   1
   0       0       0       1       1   |   2
   0       0       1       0       0   |   1
   0       0       1       0       1   |   2
   0       0       1       1       0   |   2
   0       0       1       1       1   |   3
   0       1       0       0       0   |   1
   0       1       0       0       1   |   2
   0       1       0       1       0   |   2
   0       1       0       1       1   |   3
   0       1       1       0       0   |   2
   0       1       1       0       1   |   3
   0       1       1       1       0   |   3
   0       1       1       1       1   |   4
   1       0       0       0       0   |   1
   1       0       0       0       1   |   2
   1       0       0       1       0   |   2
   1       0       0       1       1   |   3
   1       0       1       0       0   |   2
   1       0       1       0       1   |   3
   1       0       1       1       0   |   3
   1       0       1       1       1   |   4
   1       1       0       0       0   |   2
   1       1       0       0       1   |   3
   1       1       0       1       0   |   3
   1       1       0       1       1   |   4
   1       1       1       0       0   |   3
   1       1       1       0       1   |   3
   1       1       1       1       0   |   4
   1       1       1       1       1   |   5
-----------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, there are exactly 16 sequences with 3 or more heads.